# Error on eclipse debug. Cannot follow programm flow

Tags: debugging, stm32

I am using Eclipse IDE for Embedded C/C++ Developers Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0). In my project I flash and run my project in STM32l476. When I debug my code sometimes the pointer of degug does not follow the programm flow(I can track the programm flow from serial terminal printfs). Any idea why this happens ? This is my debug config
[image]

Comment: Are you compiling the code with suitable options to enable sane debug, e.g. `-O0` or `-Og`? If not, then you might see the code flow not being as expected.

Comment: As @pmacfarlane said, check your Optimization settings. Properties - C/C++ Build - Settings - MCU GCC Compiler - Optimization - Optimization Level must be set to **None (-O0)** or **Optimize Debug (-Og)**.